# Trying to add an element before a dynamically built dropdown list

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu, dynamic-data

This is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    var path = "http://shop.vodafone.co.uk",
                        phoneList = $('#phoneList');
                    $.getJSON("phones.json", function(data){
                            var option = $('option').attr('value', data);
                            var phones = [];
                            for(var phone in data) {
                                //phones.push("<option value='"+data[phone].value+"'>"+data[phone].name+"</option>");
                                phones.push(data[phone]);
                            }

                            //console.log(phones);
                            phones.sort(function(a, b){
                                var aName = a.name.toLowerCase(),
                                    bName = b.name.toLowerCase();
                                if(aName < bName) {
                                    return -1;    
                                }
                                if(aName > bName){
                                    return 1;
                                };
                                return 0;
                            });
                            var select = $('<option value="Take your pick"></option>').val();
                            var htmlElements = [];
                            for(var i = 0; i<phones.length; i++) {
                                htmlElements.push("<option value='"+phones[i].value+"'>"+phones[i].name+"</option>");
                            }
                            //htmlElements.before(select);
                            $("#phoneList").before(select).html(htmlElements.join('\n'));
                            //val = $(this).find('option:selected').val(),

                    });
                    $('.phoneSelect').bind('change', function(){
                        var url = $("#phoneList option:selected").val();
                        window.location = path + url;
                    });
            });
            })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div>
 <form class="phoneSelect" action="#">
 <select style="width: 200px" name="phoneMake" id="phoneList">
    <option selected="selected" value="Take your pick">Take your pick</option>
 </select>
</form>
</div>
```

The issue is I am trying to add the above element 
    'Take your pick' 
before the dynamically built dropdown list and all withing the same form element. 
The dropdown list data is retrieved from a JSON file.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: If i understand what you are trying to achieve here, you want to build a `select` but the first element should be `Take your pick`.

Comment: The select drop down works but I want the first element to be the display text, which isn't clickable. The other options in the dropdown will be clickable. Currently the first option in the drop down is for one of the options which should be clickable but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

try to append the numbers while looping:

```
for(var i=0; i<phones.length; i++){
    $("#phoneList").append($("<option value='"+phones[i].value+"'>"+phones[i].name+"</option>"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My issue is that with the dropdown being added dynamically and sorted it takes the first element as the default display for the drop down and makes it unclickable. I actually want to add a default display text for the dropdown.

Comment: I don't wan tot remove the first element but instead add an element as a display text before it.

Comment: That's my problem. To my knowledge the .html() overrites everything in the select id="phoneList" element including the first option value="Take your pick" element. I tried to add the option value="Take your pick" element using the .before() function but it adds it outside the dropdown.
This code builds the dropdown:
$("#phoneList").html(htmlElements.join('\n'));

I added the .before() to make it:
$("#phoneList").before(select).html(htmlElements.join('\n'));

The select variable is 'var select = $('<option value="Take your pick"></option>').val();'. That doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I thought you didn't understand my issue, will try it now.
Thanks mate, you are a genius!

Comment: Can I ask one more question?
How do I add an optgroup label="" to group the options in categories?